# Use the json variable under the pivot in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I have the data like this.

```
{
    "id":9,
    "title":"This is a gonna share event",
    "description":"Hi, this is a share event.",
    "owner":"arios",
    "start":"01\/26\/2016 12:00 AM",
    "end":"01\/27\/2016 12:00 AM",
    "type":"3",
    "allday":"",
    "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "events_id": 9,
        "eventstatus": 0
    }
}
```

I want to use the value of the eventstatus in my view file, but I can call it using the javascript. I wrote :

```
 eventAfterRender:function (event,element,view){
                if(event.pivot.evenstatus == '0'){
                    if(event.type=='1'){
                        element.css('background-color', '#0072E8');
                        element.css('border-color', '#0072E8');
                        element.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='img/eat.png' width='12' height='12'>");

                    }else if(event.type=='6'){
                        element.css('background-color', '#1C6AFF');
                        element.css('border-color', '#1C6AFF');

                    }
                }
                else if(event.pivot.eventstatus == '1'){
                    element.css('background-color', '#E81700');
                    element.css('border-color', '#E81700');
                }
            },
```

This is a many to many relationship.
I have tried this method, but it still didnt use the variable of my eventstatus.

Comment: I think you meant to use `event.pivot.eventstatus`

Comment: This didnt work, result wont change.

Comment: you are doing wrong use event.pivot.eventstatus instead of event.eventstatus.Please check your provided json format then you understand

Comment: @ImtiazPabel ya, but that still didnt works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
eventstatus = "<?php echo event->pivot->eventstatus; ?>"

if(eventstatus =='1'){...}
```

**Edit**

For pass data from `php` to `js`:

php:

```
$event = '{
"id":9,
"title":"This is a gonna share event",
"description":"Hi, this is a share event.",
"owner":"arios",
"start":"01\/26\/2016 12:00 AM",
"end":"01\/27\/2016 12:00 AM",
"type":"3",
"allday":"",
"pivot": {
    "user_id": 1,
    "events_id": 9,
    "eventstatus": 0
}
}';
$event = json_decode($event);
return view('your view', compact('event'));
```

js:

```
alert("{{$event->pivot->eventstatus}}")
```

Comment: This is under the view file, javascript?

Comment: I call the json data and perform it in my calendar view funciton.

Comment: Your calendar view function? What's this? php class? you tagged laravel framework so I think you want pass `json` from `php` to `js`

Comment: Ya, i want o pass the data from the php to js.

Comment: in `js`, this code still working: `event = {
            "id":9,
            "title":"This is a gonna share event",
            "description":"Hi, this is a share event.",
            "owner":"arios",
            "start":"01\/26\/2016 12:00 AM",
            "end":"01\/27\/2016 12:00 AM",
            "type":"3",
            "allday":"",
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 1,
                "events_id": 9,
                "eventstatus": 0
            }
        }
        alert(event.pivot.eventstatus)`

Comment: You want o pass the data from the php to js, check my edit.

Comment: I am return the json data to my view like this `$test = array_merge($eventData->toArray(),$event_in_country->toArray());

        return $test;`

Comment: I return the data to the javascript and view in my full calendar.

Comment: Look like you use `ajax`? i cant imagine your full calendar.